# MySQL creating view which is union of two tables with one tables values prefixed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union, temp-tables

I have authentication system which gets permissions from MySQL database.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE db.temp (authority VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO db.temp (authority) SELECT blog.authors.id FROM db.authors;
UPDATE db.temp SET authority=CONCAT("AUTH_",authority);

SELECT authority FROM db.temp
UNION
SELECT authority FROM db.authorities_real
```

This script works fine when executed from command line, but in Views, use of temporary tables is not allowed. Is there any way to do what i want without them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `UNION` using the `authors` table:

```
SELECT CONCAT('AUTH_',blog.authors.id)
FROM db.authors
UNION 
SELECT authority 
FROM db.authorities_real
```

Instead of creating your temp table, you will just use the `db.authors` table in the `UNION`. Doing it this way you do not have to use a temp table.

The `UNION` will remove any duplicates from the query. If you don't mind the duplicates or do not expect any then I would use a `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine those statements into a single one:

```
SELECT concat('AUTH_', blog.authors.id) as authority FROM db.authors
UNION -- all ?
SELECT authority FROM db.authorities_real`
```